# Do hearing-impaired individuals need more sleep?

Tags: sleep-cycles, cognitive-science, hearing-impaired, auditory-cortex

I'm a hearing-impaired individual, but because I was born with this disability, I never researched it because it was never "new" and "exciting" to me, but a friend recently informed me that hearing-impaired individuals actually require more sleep than most because their brains are constantly operating on a higher level as they have to work harder to interpret sounds, etc. For most of my life, I have been on the lethargic side of things, but I was wondering if this is a factually accurate statement. It makes logical sense to me, but can someone point me in the direction of research?

On average, what is the optimal amount of sleep a hearing-impaired individual needs? When was this discovered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hot topic in hearing research right now is [listening effort](http://www.audiology.org/news/listening-effort-and-fatigue). The basic idea is that is that individuals with hearing loss need to use additional cognitive resources to process sounds. There is also [evidence](http://jap.physiology.org/content/106/3/857.long) that mental fatigue impairs physical performance. While I think this evidence provides the basis for arguing that hard of hearing individuals might need more sleep, I am not aware of any direct evidence.